# warning: format '%d' expects type 'int', but argument 6 has type 'long int'

Tags: c++

I receive this warning during the compilation process.

> "warning: format '%d' expects type 'int', but argument 6 has type 'long int'

Should I change `%d` into `%lu` ?

EDIT:
This is a part of the code.

```
if (item->GetVnum() == DRAGON_HEART_VNUM)
{
    sprintf(buf, "Inc %ds by item{VN:%d SOC%d:%d}", ret, item->GetVnum(), ITEM_SOCKET_CHARGING_AMOUNT_IDX, item->GetSocket(ITEM_SOCKET_CHARGING_AMOUNT_IDX));
}
else
{
    sprintf(buf, "Inc %ds by item{VN:%d VAL%d:%d}", ret, item->GetVnum(), ITEM_VALUE_CHARGING_AMOUNT_IDX, item->GetValue(ITEM_VALUE_CHARGING_AMOUNT_IDX));
}
```

Comment: what is your compiler?

Comment: How would we know what you should change? Maybe you should change the format to `%ld`. Maybe you should change the argument to `int`. It is like asking where's the error in `2 + 3 = 6`. Should it be `2 + 3 = 5`? Or should it be `2 * 3 = 6`. Only you know what you really need.

Comment: Also, errors like that are possible when, for example, one tries to print a `ptrdiff_t` value with `%d` format, and `ptrdiff_t` just happens to stand for `long int`. In that case you should change the format to `%td`.

Comment: You're asking us to comment on code you haven't shown us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the format specifier from `%d` to `%ld`, or change the data type of argument to be `int`.  (`%lu` would be for `unsigned long int`.)

Alternatively, you could use `std::cin` for input and `std::cout` for output.  You don't have to use printf/scanf-style type codes; the correct overload for the type of operand would be called automatically.

Answer (score 0):

i get the same warning but then i searched on-line and the best solution i got was--Doesn't matter just run the program and it works.Because i tried every single thing i could but i couldn't get rid of that 'Warning' so i kept surfing on net n on some geek site i was told to leave the code untouched and just run it and it worked...